# Tag merge request: [git-submodule] and [git-submodules]

Tags: support, retag-request

The [git-submodule](/questions/tagged/git-submodule) tag should be merged into the [git-submodules](/questions/tagged/git-submodules) tag.

There are only 11 questions with the former, and several of those have both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I retagged the questions with [git-submodule](/questions/tagged/git-submodule) (11 is clearly in the doable manually range). That tag is now orphan, and will cease to exist within the next 24h.