# Changed tag imagemagik to imagemagick; best practice for retagging?

Tags: discussion, tags

There were 19 questions tagged [imagemagik](/questions/tagged/imagemagik), which is a typo for [imagemagick](/questions/tagged/imagemagick).  Some had both tags, some just had [imagemagik](/questions/tagged/imagemagik).

I've just manually re-tagged all 19 questions, so [imagemagik](/questions/tagged/imagemagik) is now an orphan tag and, as I understand it, should vanish in about 24 hours.

[The last time I saw something like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118224/tag-merge-request-git-submodule-and-git-submodules/118233#118233) ([git-submodule](/questions/tagged/git-submodule) vs. [git-submodules](/questions/tagged/git-submodules)), I posted a retag-request here, and another user manually retagged the 11 affected questions, so I decided to go ahead and do the same thing with this.

For future reference, when is it better to manually retag questions vs. posting a request here?  And if I manually retag questions to eliminate an incorrect tag, should I post here or just quietly do it?

Comment: If the misspelled tag keeps reappearing, we can also set up a synonym to automatically translate it to the correct version.

Comment: The New Tag Deletionist Cabal shall ensure that the incorrectly spelled tag does not reappear.

Answer (score 4):

You only need to ask if you're not sure; in the case of a misspelling obviously it should be fixed. As for asking vs. doing it yourself, it comes down to how much work is involved. Each edit is going to push the post to the front page, and people get annoyed if the whole front page is flooded with old questions that had a single tag changed. Tag merges avoid that, so if there's a lot of posts that's the way to go, and it means you don't have to sit there manually retagging each. I don't think there's a hard rule about it though; probably around 25 is when you should just get a mod to merge them instead of retagging them all

Comment: Hmm.  Is 25 a bit high?  Manually editing those 19 questions took me a while, partly because some of them had "problem" or "help" in their titles. How long would it take a moderator to merge the tags? I'm all for using what privileges I have to take some of the work load off the moderators, but it's O(N) if I do it and O(1) (I presume) if a moderator does it.

Comment: @KeithThompson They just have a page for specifying the source/target tags; it's just about not constantly annoying them every time a tag needs merging. Maybe 25 is too high, but don't get them to merge a tag if there are 3 instances is what I was going for

Comment: Ok.  I guess I'm looking for a consensus on where the cutoff is.  As you mention, pushing posts to the front page is another problem^H^H^H^H^H^H^H issue.  (I'm not optimistic that I'll get a definitive answer, though; this probably isn't a big enough deal to be worth the effort of coming up with one.)